# ssh cannot open remote window, Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: ssh, remote, nautilus, segmentation-fault

Actually, the remote window can be opened, but only for a short time. I mean it is OK to open the remote window when ssh connected, but the remote window cannot be opened later, for example after 30 minutes, and this message is shown:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

When I tried to run `nautilus`:

```
(nautilus:29991): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: localhost:10.0
```

Can anyone help me figure this out?